# Rand(); with exclusion to and already randomly generated number..?

Tags: php, arrays, random, unique

I have a function which calls a users associated users from a table. The function then uses the rand(); function to chose from the array 5 randomly selected userID's however!...

In the case where a user doesnt have many associated users but above the min (if below the 5 it just returns the array as it is) then it gives bad results due to repeat rand numbers...

How can overcome this or exclude a previously selected rand number from the next rand(); function call.

Here is the section of code doing the work. Bare in mind this must be highly efficient as this script is used everywhere.

```
$size = sizeof($users)-1;
    $nusers[0] = $users[rand(0,$size)];
    $nusers[1] = $users[rand(0,$size)];
    $nusers[2] = $users[rand(0,$size)];
    $nusers[3] = $users[rand(0,$size)];
    $nusers[4] = $users[rand(0,$size)];

    return $nusers;
```

Thanks in advance!
Stefan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php):

```
$users = range(3, 10); // this is just example data
$nusers = array_rand($users, 5); // pick 5 unique KEYS from $users

foreach ($nusers as $key => $value)
{
  $nusers[$key] = $nusers[$value]; // replace keys with actual values
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($nusers);
echo '</pre>';
```

**PS: [Read this](http://dog-net.org/content/development/php/rand-or-mt-rand-/) to know why you should use `mt_rand()` instead of `rand()`.**

Comment: For whatever reason, I can't load that link.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to shuffle your array items, use [`shuffle`](http://php.net/shuffle):

```
shuffle($users);
return $users;
```

Note that `shuffle` requires pass by reference. So you need to pass a variable that’s is then shuffled.